# How upload Image with Swift5 and PHP to Server?

Tags: php, swift, swift5

I'm trying to upload image to a local server using swift5 and php , Xcode Version 12.5.1 , Can you help me debug the code, or give me an example ?

[Image upload example with Swift and PHP](https://swiftdeveloperblog.com/image-upload-example/)

I downloaded this example and change but it doesn't work, only folders created work

The modifications in the code :

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var myActivityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView!
    @IBOutlet weak var myImageView: UIImageView!

    @IBAction func uploadButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
      myImageUploadRequest()
    }

    @IBAction func selectPhotoButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        let myPickerController = UIImagePickerController()
        myPickerController.delegate = self;
        myPickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerController.SourceType.photoLibrary
        
        self.present(myPickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        myImageView.image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage
        myImageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }




    func generateBoundaryString() -> String
    {
        return "Boundary-\(UUID().uuidString)"
    }

    
    func myImageUploadRequest()
       {
         
           let myUrl = NSURL(string: "http://localhost/~*******/PHP/App/scripts/imageUpload.php");
           //let myUrl = NSURL(string: "http://www.boredwear.com/utils/postImage.php");
           
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url:myUrl! as URL);
        request.httpMethod = "POST";
           
           let param = [
               "firstName"  : "Sergey",
               "lastName"    : "Kargopolov",
               "userId"    : "9"
           ]
           
           let boundary = generateBoundaryString()
           
           request.setValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

            let imageData = myImageView.image!.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1)

           
           if(imageData==nil)  {
            
            return;
            
           }
 
        print("imageData =\(imageData as Any)")
           
           //request.HTTPBody = createBodyWithParameters(param, filePathKey: "file", imageDataKey: imageData!, boundary: boundary)
           
        request.httpBody = createBodyWithParameters(parameters: param, filePathKey: "file", imageDataKey: imageData! as NSData, boundary: boundary) as Data

           myActivityIndicator.startAnimating();
           
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {
               data, response, error in
               
               if error != nil {
                print("error=\(String(describing: error))")
                   return
               }
               
               // You can print out response object
            print("******* response = \(String(describing: response))")
               
               // Print out reponse body
            let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
               print("****** response data = \(responseString!)")
               
               do {
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as? NSDictionary
                   
                print(json as Any)
                   

                   
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.myActivityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                    self.myImageView.image = nil;
                }
                
                
               }catch
               {
                   print(error)
               }
               
           }
           
           task.resume()
       }
    

    
    func createBodyWithParameters(parameters: [String: String]?, filePathKey: String?, imageDataKey: NSData, boundary: String) -> NSData {
        let body = NSMutableData();

        if parameters != nil {
            for (key, value) in parameters! {

                
                body.appendString(string: "--\(boundary)\r\n")
                body.appendString(string: "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\"\r\n\r\n")
                body.appendString(string: "\(value)\r\n")
            }
        }
       
        let filename = "user-profile.jpg"
        let mimetype = "image/jpg"
        
        body.appendString(string: "--\(boundary)\r\n")
        body.appendString(string: "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(filePathKey!)\"; filename=\"\(filename)\"\r\n")
        body.appendString(string: "Content-Type: \(mimetype)\r\n\r\n")
        body.append(imageDataKey as Data)
        body.appendString(string: "\r\n")
        
        return body
    }
    
     
 
    
}
    
extension NSMutableData {
   
    func appendString(string: String) {
        //let data = string.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: true)
        let data = string.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: true)

        append(data!)
    }
    
    
    
    
}
```

error message:

```
imageData =Optional(2322803 bytes)
2022-12-12 04:50:44.756347+0300 ImageUploadExample[7201:311148] [] nw_protocol_get_quic_image_block_invoke dlopen libquic failed
******* response = Optional(<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x6000031e55a0> { URL: http://localhost/~*******/PHP/App/scripts/imageUpload.php } { Status Code: 200, Headers {
    Connection =     (
        "Keep-Alive"
    );
    "Content-Type" =     (
        "text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    );
    Date =     (
        "Mon, 12 Dec 2022 01:50:44 GMT"
    );
    "Keep-Alive" =     (
        "timeout=5, max=100"
    );
    Server =     (
        "Apache/2.4.48 (Unix) PHP/8.1.13"
    );
    "Transfer-Encoding" =     (
        Identity
    );
    "X-Powered-By" =     (
        "PHP/8.1.13"
    );
} })
****** response data = {"Message":"Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.","Status":"Error","userId":"9"}
Optional({
    Message = "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    Status = Error;
    userId = 9;
})
```

Comment: Given the response with the error is coming from PHP, it'd be useful to dump the error from the serverside, it seems this line is failing: `move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $target_dir`, it could be that the disk is full, it could be the webserver doesn't have permission to write to that directory, etc.

Comment: @ZacharyCraig Thank you, I have permission to write, I tried this example: `<?php
if(isset($_POST['img_submit'])){
 
 $img_name=$_FILES['img_upload']['name'];
 $tmp_img_name=$_FILES['img_upload']['tmp_name'];
 move_uploaded_file($tmp_img_name,$img_name);
}

?>
<form action='' method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
<input type='file' name='img_upload'><br><br>
<input type='submit' name='img_submit'>
</form>`